# F# Async: equivalent of Boost asio's strands

Tags: asynchronous, concurrency, f#

Boost's [asio](https://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.18.0/doc/) library allows the serialisation of asynchronous code in the following way. Handlers to asynchronous functions such as those which read from a stream, may be associated to a [strand](https://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.18.0/doc/asio/reference/io_context__strand.html). A strand is associated with an "IO context". An IO context owns a thread pool. However many threads in the pool, it is guaranteed that no two handlers associated with the same strand are run concurrently. This makes it possible, for instance, to implement a state machine as if it were single-threaded, where all handlers for that machine serialise over a private strand.

I have been trying to figure out how this might be done with F#'s `Async`. I could not find any way to make sure that chosen sets of `Async` processes never run concurrently. Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

It would be useful to know what is the use case that you are trying to implement. I don't think F# `async` has anything that would directly map to strands and you would likely use different techniques for implementing different things that might all be implemented using strands.

For example, if you are concerend with reading data from a stream, F# `async` block lets you write code that is asynchronous but sequential. The following runs a single logical process (which might be moved between threads of a thread pool when you wait using `let!`):

```
let readTest () = async { 
  let fs = File.OpenRead(@"C:\Temp\test.fs")
  let buffer = Array.zeroCreate 10
  let mutable read = 1
  while read <> 0 do
    let! r = fs.AsyncRead(buffer, 0, 10)
    printfn "Read: %A" buffer.[0 .. r-1]
    read <- r }

readTest() |> Async.Start
```

If you wanted to deal with events that occur without any control (i.e. push based rather than pull based), for example, when you cannot ask the system to read next buffer of data, you could serialize the events using a `MailboxProcessor`. The following sends two messages to the agent almost at the same time, but they are processed sequentially, with 1 second delay:

```
let agent = MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox -> async {
  while true do 
    let! msg = inbox.Receive()
    printfn "Got: %s" msg
    do! Async.Sleep(1000)
})

agent.Post("hello")
agent.Post("world")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. `MaliboxProcessor` is closer to the functionality I am looking for. A summary of what I am looking for would be this: a way to asynchronously launch arbitrary code on a chosen strand, such that no more than one concurrent operation executes for a given strand. Is there a general solution to this which avoids any explicit synchronisation above specifying a strand?

Comment: This could be done if an asynchronous lock existed.

Comment: Another could use a MailboxProcessor. A wrapper could be made around the code to be asynchronously executed, which itself would be a callback. When called, it would message the strand's mailbox with the wrapped callback (along with its arguments), entering the execution queue. There would be an asynchronous process taking callbacks from the queue and executing them indefinitely.

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure the last solution would work in F#. Would be interested to hear your comments.

Comment: @justinpc I think having a wrapper around a mailbox processor - and using that as an execution queue - would work. The only issue with mailbox processors is that they have a potentially unbounded queue for messages, so you need to make sure you never need to do more work than it can manage.

Comment: I am going to implement this solution when I am able to. I haven't started working with F# yet.